# Printing user input in array says null

Tags: java

I am trying to print user input from an array to display in java. When i run this, it just prints out "null" for each amount no matter what the user inputs. I am a beginner at java and want to learn more about arrays, and I can't seem to figure this out.

```
String itemAmount = ss.getInputString("How many items?");
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(itemAmount);

    String[] Items = new String[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {
        ss.getInputString("Please enter items?");

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {
        ss.println((Items[i]));
    }
```

Also, how would i be able to print the items, for example user inputs 3 items -> "Eggs",  "Bacon", "Tomato" how would I print this to show in a line separated by commas.

Comment: I can't see the code where you put stuff in `Items`. Where is it?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think that's the issue. He is most likely reading a String, but is nowhere adding it into the array.

Comment: You mean like the array for items? the user inputs items using the input box dialogue but I don't know how to display the items the user writes in.

Comment: @Scretqer you are not storing the values that are read in the array, that is your problem

Comment: @Stultuske yes, I don't know how to add the user input to an array and display it, how would I be able to do this efficiently?

Comment: @Scretqer check Federico's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `gt` is, but since you're using it this way

```
String itemAmount = gt.getInputString("How many items?");
```

I guess it's some sort of wrapper around the standard input.

You can use it the same way to populate an array, one item at a time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Items.length; i++) {
    Item[i] = gt.getInputString("Please enter items?");
}
```

You seem to be able to use the array in the other loop, so I'll assume you don't need further explanation.

Then to print them on a single line, separated by a comma you can use the `join` method of `String` (note: you need to convert your array to a `List`, first)

```
String joinedString = String.join(", ", Arrays.asList(Items));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are checking the length of wrong array/string in second for loop. It should be **Items.length** not **Appliances.length**